# If statment in angular6

Tags: html, typescript, angular6

I want to write if statement for two different languages like Arabic and English for which if language is Arabic then the text will be moved to right to left which is rtl and default in English.

I tried using if statement but not working

```
*ngIf="lang==='ar' || dir==='rtl'"
```

Comment: Did you try with == operator, and not === one?

Comment: Can you post a [MCVE]? You can rely on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/).

Comment: yes i try with those operator as well